# Automatically determine if user-defined function is equivalent to the implicit one

Tags: c++, c++11

Sometimes, users implement functions with the equivalent functionality as their implicitly defined versions. For example, a copy constructor which simply calls the copy constructor of all its members.

```
struct A
{
    int B;
    A(const A& a) : B(a.B) { }
}
```

This is undesirable, because it causes additional maintenance, for example if the class members are renamed/reordered, etc., and reduces readability. Also, adding these functions also means that functions such as `std::is_trivially_copy_constructable` claim the type is cannot be trivially copy constructed (but in practice, it actually could be).

I have a code base where this seems to be a common occurrence, which I would like to rectify, by deleting these implementations. However, I am uneasy about removing functionality that seems to be identical to implicit implementation, in case it might not actually be equivalent. Is there a method for determining  whether a function is equivalent to its implicit version? (Using any toolset/language variation/etc is acceptable).

Comment: It is, in general, impossible to produce an algorithm which either says "these two functions are the same", or "these two functions are different".  However, it *is* possible to create an algorithm which gives either one of those answers or "not sure".  Provided it doesn't say "not sure" too often, such a tool can be useful.  Can you construct something from the LLVM toolkit (clang)?

Comment: I don't have any experience with the LLVM toolkit - could you expand?

Comment: Neither do I.  I just know that they aim to provide tools that enable static analysers to be built: http://llvm.org/  In particular, http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/, and either add a checker or a compiler warning.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to not try to programmatically determine if these functions are the same as the default implementation, because the difference *might actually be a mistake* (and they were supposed to have the normal default behavior).

Instead I would just suggest to write up a set of unit tests that take care of testing the *expected* behavior of the various functions, and then make sure they pass on the default implementations. Then not only do you have a test framework for future enhancements you can be confident the functions did what you wanted.

Comment: While I think this is a good answer, it requires an huge additional level of code maintenance (writing and maintaining unit tests), that I was trying to avoid.