# Why is my hand-written copy constructor generate different code than the default one?

Tags: c++, g++

I was trying to come up with an answer for a question I had a while ago ([Automatically determine if user-defined function is equivalent to the implicit one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257664/automatically-determine-if-user-defined-function-is-equivalent-to-the-implicit-o)). My thought was that I would compile in and out the copy constructor, and then disassemble the code, and check that they were identical. The code:

```
struct A
{
    int B;
    A() : B(0) { }
#ifdef COPY_CONSTRUCTOR
    A(const A& a) : B(a.B) { }
#endif
};

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    A a;
    A b(a);
    printf("%d", b.B);
}
```

Compiled with (cygwin gcc v4.9.3):

```
gcc -o a1.exe main.cpp -std=c++11 -g -O0 -DCOPY_CONSTRUCTOR
gcc -o a2.exe main.cpp -std=c++11 -g -O0 -fno-elide-constructors
```

And then dumping the disassembly the the copy constructors (`_ZN1AC1ERKS_` is the mangled name of A's copy constructor):

```
gdb -batch -ex 'file a1.exe' -ex 'disass _ZN1AC1ERKS_'
```

Produces:

```
Dump of assembler code for function A::A(A const&):
   0x0000000100401770 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000100401771 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000100401774 <+4>:     mov    %rcx,0x10(%rbp)
   0x0000000100401778 <+8>:     mov    %rdx,0x18(%rbp)
   0x000000010040177c <+12>:    mov    0x18(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000100401780 <+16>:    mov    (%rax),%edx
   0x0000000100401782 <+18>:    mov    0x10(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000100401786 <+22>:    mov    %edx,(%rax)
   0x0000000100401788 <+24>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000100401789 <+25>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
```

And:

```
gdb -batch -ex 'file a2.exe' -ex 'disass _ZN1AC1ERKS_'
```

Produces:

```
Dump of assembler code for function A::A(A const&):
   0x0000000100401770 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000100401771 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000100401774 <+4>:     mov    %rcx,0x10(%rbp)
   0x0000000100401778 <+8>:     mov    %rdx,0x18(%rbp)
   0x000000010040177c <+12>:    mov    0x10(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000100401780 <+16>:    mov    0x18(%rbp),%rdx
   0x0000000100401784 <+20>:    mov    (%rdx),%edx
   0x0000000100401786 <+22>:    mov    %edx,(%rax)
   0x0000000100401788 <+24>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000100401789 <+25>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
```

They are the same, except that the line `mov 0x10(%rbp),%rax` occurs in a different order. In this case, it's innocuous, but obviously makes equivalence detection harder. What is the explanation for the difference?

Comment: So, it "makes equivalence detection harder"? why, who told you that equivalence detection at the assembly level was going to be easy?

Comment: A compiler is not required to generate identical code for a default constructor as if it was spelled out, using explicit C++ code. More than likely, gcc runs dedicated code that generates the default copy-constructor code, while the code for a constructor, copy or otherwise, gets handled by general purpose code.

Comment: Generated machine code will probably be identical if you bump up the optimization level.

Comment: @NikolaiFetissov: yes - if I compile with `-O3` (and add `fno-inlines`), then they become equivalent (and *much* shorter). Seems like the answer here is an combination of these three comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your question got me curious so I had to see for myself. You can check [here for version 1](https://godbolt.org/g/M4aYui) and [here for version 2](https://godbolt.org/g/XWHJhk) to see that the results are actually identical.

Both variants are optimized away!

This is the disassembly:

```
.LC0:
        .string "%d"
Test():
        push    0
        push    OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    printf
        pop     eax
        pop     edx
        push    0
        push    OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    printf
        pop     ecx
        pop     eax
        ret
```

To understand why the non-optimized versions differ, you would probably have to check the sources of gcc.

Visual Studio also gives identical results:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    A b(a);
    printf("%d", b.B);
00B41000  push        0  
00B41002  push        0B499A0h  
00B41007  call        printf (0B4102Dh)  
    printf("%d", a.B);
00B4100C  push        0  
00B4100E  push        0B499A4h  
00B41013  call        printf (0B4102Dh)  
00B41018  add         esp,10h  
    return 0;
0127101B  xor         eax,eax  
}
0127101D  ret
```

Comment: Your test is showing the disassembly for the Test function, not the copy constructor of A. So, this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito well, the idea is that since both get optimized away, both are identical, no?